# Different LaunchScreen.storyboard For Different Devices

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, launch

For my app's LaunchScreen I am using a `.storyboard`. I there created a `UIVisualEffectsView` containing blur and vibrancy with labels and an image. This works perfectly fine but I came across the older iPads like iPad 2 or Retina that are apparently not able to display blur.
Now, for those I would like to do something else since it looks weird. As I would prefer a storyboard over LaunchImages, I have the following questions:

1. Can I create a different `LaunchScreen.storyboard` depending on the device?
2. Is it possible to use a LaunchImage instead, but for older devices only and keep the LaunchScreen for the newer ones?